# Почему логические or и | работают по разному?

Tags: python

Почему логические or и | работают по разному? Вот собственно и весь вопрос.

```
In [1]: 5 or 15
Out[1]: 5

In [1]: 5 | 15
Out[2]: 15
```

И было бы здорово, чтобы кто-то объяснил смысл такого кодирования этих операций. А то не знаю, что сказать ученикам ))

Comment: | это математический оператор, а or - Логический

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`|` — это оператор [**побитового**](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F) ИЛИ.

Результат получается путём применения ИЛИ попарно к битам переданных чисел:

```
0101
1111
____
1111 = 15
```

Comment: ОЙ моя оплошность....
А скажите зачем  5 or 15  дает 5, а не ожидаемое True?
В чем смысл?
Я знаю, что так в документации, но зачем

Comment: @VasylKolomiets Потому что (в грубом приближении) `or` вычисляет и возвращает то что слева, если оно True (а ненулевое число считается True). Иначе вычисляет и возвращает то что справа.

Comment: @VasylKolomiets Это просто бывает удобно. Например, можно присвоить переменной значение по умолчанию без условных конструкций: `x = y or z`, вместо `x = y if y else z`